# {% extends .. %} doesn't run javascript in child template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to inject some javascript blocks into my parent template but they don't run. My templates are very straightforward, so I am simplifying:

base.html

```
{% load i18n static %}
<html>
<head>
..
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
...
{% block specificjs %} {% endblock %}
```

child.html

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% load i18n static %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
{% block specificjs %} <script> console.log('blah'); </script> {% endblock %}
```

So whenever I click on a button with href='link_to_child_view', it goes through the view and no blocks have been included/run

When I refresh the child.html page, it load all the injected js, css, etc.

I wonder, do I need Jinja2 to run extends, etc. ? I thought it belongs to Django by default.. If Jinja2 is not required, what am I doing wrong?

I also tried the following three methods to render/return but no difference affected:

```
# return TemplateResponse(request, 'child.html', locals())
# return render(request, 'child.html', locals())
# return render_to_response(, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: You have confirmed that the JavaScript *should* be running in the final generated HTML, right?

Comment: The first thing to do is to check the outputted HTML. (You sound somewhat confused by where things are run. Django will insert your code into HTML, which will be returned to the browser. Once that arrives at the browser the JavaScript will be run.)